# ExpandableGridView onScrollListener not Working

Tags: android

I've tried almost every Answers and solution related to this but it doesn't works for me. Help me out.

Here is my code of my ExpandableGridView. Please through it.

This is my ExpnadableView:-

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {
boolean expanded = false;
public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
if (isExpanded()) {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
} else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
```

and implementation of it:-

```
mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int                   
visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    int currentFirstVisPos = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
System.out.println("UUUUUUUUU "+myLastVisiblePos);
myLastVisiblePos = currentFirstVisPos;
}
});
```

Comment: i have added the code, you can check it.